# react-create-app heroku not running app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I created a react app with this [buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-web-server).

I also added react router to it, so that my index.js now looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './views/Home';
import CreateRestaurant from './views/CreateRestaurant';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route
} from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
            <Route path="/createRestaurant" component={ CreateRestaurant }/>
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

When I run this locally it renders my home.js view. However when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I get a successful build but when I open the app via the heroku URL

I still get the standard page saying:

*Welcome to React*

*To get started, edit src/App.js and save to reload.*

How do I get heroku to display my app?

Comment: did you build your app before deploying it to heroku?

Comment: actually no, as it seems the build is created when the app gets pushed to heroku master

Comment: You dont need to create a build before deploying. There might be something wrong with your webpack config. Try building it locally and serving the build

Comment: @Swapnil where do I find my webpack config with this buildpack? It seems to be nowhere in my directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build react app before deploying to heroku.

There is a tool to automate this process

[create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

The steps required are following

```
heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack https://github.com/mars/create-
react-app-buildpack.git
git add .
git commit -m "Start with create-react-app"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

Comment: this is the buildpack i used. However I still get the standard page when pushing to heroku master

Comment: This helped! I had to do a ```git add ```.